# encoding issue using php and mysql, wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, utf-8

I have the following text which I manually enter into the wordpress posts table

```
&amp;#226;&#8364;&#353;
```

I encode into utf-8 using:

```
$text = "&amp;#226;&#8364;&#353;";
$enc = mb_detect_encoding($text, "UTF-8,ISO-8859-1");
$hotelDescription   = iconv($enc, "UTF-8", $text);
```

However, when wordpress echoes it it displays

```
ââ‚¬Å¡
```

Any ideas who I can output the correct characters?

Comment: There is a difference between [character encoding](http://gedcom-parse.sourceforge.net/doc/encoding.html) and [html entities](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify that the page displaying that string render using UTF-8 encoding. The output you posted is the iso-8859-1 version of that utf-8 string. Assuming the data is being stored in the database correctly as UTF-8 ensure the page where this string is being rendered has the following meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing the & before #226;